# Querying system data views only for parent account

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sfmc-business-unit

Querying System data views and wanted to get results only for parent account. here parent account is acting like any other Business Unit. while query returns the results for all Business units. How can i limit the query to return results specifically for parent account.

I have got below query

```
    Select s.X, j.Y, o.Z from [_Job] 
Join [_Open] on j.jobid = o.jobid
```

joining it with _subscribers but it is giving results for all business units. prefixing ent.[_subscribers] throwing an error as I'm running the query in parent account.

error says: Table has multi-part specifications.

can anyone help with the query to get results from data views only for Parent account (Not including business units)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WHERE` clause and use the `AccountID`. The `AccountId` is also known as the MID. You can highlight over the dropdown of your business unit to locate this number.

```
Select 
s.X
, j.Y
, o.Z 
from [_Job] j
Join [_Open] o on j.jobid = o.jobid
WHERE j.AccountID = '123456'
```

Comment: Thank Jackson, but I am doing 0.IsUnique = 1 but it is giving multiple results for same email address. how can i limit email address to be shown only once in the result?